# Accessing and populating a Word 2007 document templates Quick Parts using C# and Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word?

Tags: c#-4.0, ms-word

I have created a document template file (.dotx) in Word 2007 and in this I have created a Quick Part. I have been attempting to access this quick part programmatically using C# and the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word namespace. Once I have access to the Quick Part I want to populate its fields with the properties of a POCO, then replicate this for all the POCO's in a List.

So far I have not been successful. Has anyone had any luck with this?

Note: I do not want to use the Open XML SDK if at all possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I could access a Quick Part from a Document Template file using the following code:

```
    private BuildingBlock GetQuickPartFromTemplate(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApplication, string wordTemplateDocumentPath, object quickPartName)
    {
        return (from Template template in wordApplication.Templates
                where template.FullName.Contains(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(wordTemplateDocumentpath))
                let index = quickPartName
                select template.BuildingBlockEntries.Item(ref quickPartName)).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

The first parameter is the Word Application, the second is the path of the Document Template file, while the third is the name of the Quick Part in the template.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach would be to populate a Custom XML part with the contents of your POCO.

The data would appear on the surface of the document via data bound content controls. A data bound content control identifies the data to which it is bound via XPath.

See generally http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433638%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the alternative approach. It is appreciated.